# Logitech Lua Repeat while G-Key is being held

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Hello guys I want to write a Lua Script thats repeating the codeblock below as long as I'm holding a specific key (best would be G-Key, but is not that important) and instantly stopps when I release the key. As a workaround I just made it that it repeats 6 times and stops, but thats not actually what I want.

Thank you very much!

```
if event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 5  then


 for i=1,6 do
if i == 1 then
    end
         PressKey("r")
    Sleep(math.random(50, 100)) 
    ReleaseKey("r")
    Sleep(math.random(2300, 2450)) 
    PressKey("r")
    Sleep(math.random(50, 100)) 
    ReleaseKey("r")
    Sleep(math.random(100, 175)) 
if i == 6 then
    OutputLogMessage("Finished!... ")
end
end
end
```

Comment: What are you using: LGS or GHUB?

Comment: Do you have a Logitech mouse?  Or you only have Logitech keyboard (having G5 key)?

Comment: Does your keyboard have `M1`,`M2`,`M3` buttons in the left upper conner?

Comment: I'm using G-Hub and I got a G502 Mouse and G910 Keyborad :) and yes it got the M1,M2,M3 buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using GHUB and having both a Logitech keyboard and a Logitech mouse (both devices are programmable via GHUB).

**Step 1.**
Make sure you're not using MouseButton#4 ("back") in the game.
If you don't use MB#4 in the game, just skip "Step 1".
If some action is assigned to MB#4 in the game, do the following:

- choose keyboard button you don't currently use in the game
  (let assume the `F12` key is not currently used)
- goto GHUB (mouse device, assignments section, KEYS tab);
  bind `F12` to your physical MB#4
- goto game options;
  bind the old action to `F12` instead of MB#4

Now when you press physical MB#4, the game sees `F12` and activates your old action.

---

**Step 2.**
Goto GHUB (mouse device, assignments section)
Unbind "Back" from MB#4 (if you have not done it already in Step 1)

---

**Step 3.**
Goto GHUB (keyboard device, assignments section, SYSTEM tab)
Bind "Back" to key G5

---

**Step 4.**
The script.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
      Sleep(10)
      while IsMouseButtonPressed(4) do
         PressKey("r")
         Sleep(math.random(50, 100)) 
         ReleaseKey("r")
         Sleep(math.random(2300, 2450)) 
         PressKey("r")
         Sleep(math.random(50, 100)) 
         ReleaseKey("r")
         Sleep(math.random(100, 175)) 
      end
      OutputLogMessage("Finished!...\n")
   end
end
```

---

**UPDATE:**
Script for toggling G5:

```
local state, prev_btn, prev_rel

local function Sleep2(delay)
   local tm = GetRunningTime() + delay
   while true do
      local time_left = tm - GetRunningTime()
      if time_left <= 0 then
         return
      end
      Sleep(math.min(time_left, 20))
      local curr_btn = IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
      local curr_rel = prev_btn and not curr_btn
      state, prev_btn, prev_rel = state or prev_rel and curr_rel, curr_btn, prev_rel or curr_rel
   end
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
      state = not state
      if state then
         Sleep(10)
         state = IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
         if state then
            prev_btn, prev_rel, state = state
            repeat
               PressKey("r")
               Sleep2(math.random(50, 100))
               ReleaseKey("r")
               Sleep2(math.random(2300, 2450))
               PressKey("r")
               Sleep2(math.random(50, 100))
               ReleaseKey("r")
               Sleep2(math.random(100, 175))
            until state
            OutputLogMessage("Finished!...\n")
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: ty mate - you are my personal hero!

Comment: Would it also be possible to program this as a toggle?

Comment: You are the best!

Comment: I'm getting C:\LGS extension\LGS_extension.lua:9: attempt to index a nil value (global 'math') error after reinstalling G-Hub... not matter if I'm using your extension or not... is there any fix for that?

Comment: It seems the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316973/logitech-math-random-not-working-in-latest-update) is in GHUB.  Please post the output of the following script to pastebin: `function OnEvent(event, arg) if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then for k in pairs(_G) do OutputLogMessage(k.."\n") end end end`

Comment: Please also upload somewhere the new pdf documentation (in the Lua Script editor menu `Help` - `Scripting API`)

Comment: Try the fix posted in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316973/logitech-math-random-not-working-in-latest-update)

Comment: Hey tyvm, looks like a lot of good work you have done so far!- I guess I'll be just switching back to lgs - seems easier, I guess? Do I just bind the back button to G5 as in G-Hub?

Comment: Yes, the same can be done in LGS.  Does my fix work in GHUB?

Comment: Didn't try tbh, I was so pissed of by ghub that I instantly deinstalled it XD