# math library is missing in the latest update of Logitech G-Hub

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

local delay = math.random(25, 50)

[string "LuaVM"]:5: attempt to index a nil value (global 'math')

I can't use math.random anymore is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: What release is "the latest"?  Are you talking about LGS or GHUB?

Comment: On GHUB Version  2020.10.6293

Answer (score 2):

If `math` library is missed you can insert the following code block at the beginning of your script.
It will not fix the whole `math` library, but only some of the most frequently used functions (including `math.random`).
It will also fix the following errors:

> bad argument #1 to 'Sleep' (number has no integer representation)

> attempt to call a nil value (field 'getn')

```
do
   local state_8, state_45, cached_bits, cached_bits_qty = 2, 0, 0, 0
   local prev_width, prev_bits_in_factor, prev_k = 0
   for c in GetDate():gmatch"." do
      state_45 = state_45 % 65537 * 23456 + c:byte()
   end

   local function get_53_random_bits()
      local value53 = 0
      for shift = 26, 27 do
         local p = 2^shift
         state_45 = (state_45 * 233 + 7161722017421) % 35184372088832
         repeat state_8 = state_8 * 76 % 257 until state_8 ~= 1
         local r = state_8 % 32
         local n = state_45 / 2^(13 - (state_8 - r) / 32)
         n = (n - n%1) % 2^32 / 2^r
         value53 = value53 * p + ((n%1 * 2^32) + (n - n%1)) % p
      end
      return value53
   end
   
   for j = 1, 10 do get_53_random_bits() end

   local function get_random_bits(number_of_bits)
      local pwr_number_of_bits = 2^number_of_bits
      local result
      if number_of_bits <= cached_bits_qty then
         result = cached_bits % pwr_number_of_bits
         cached_bits = (cached_bits - result) / pwr_number_of_bits
      else
         local new_bits = get_53_random_bits()
         result = new_bits % pwr_number_of_bits
         cached_bits = (new_bits - result) / pwr_number_of_bits * 2^cached_bits_qty + cached_bits
         cached_bits_qty = 53 + cached_bits_qty
      end
      cached_bits_qty = cached_bits_qty - number_of_bits
      return result
   end

   table = table or {}
   table.getn = table.getn or function(x) return #x end

   math = math or {}
   math.huge  = math.huge  or 1/0
   math.abs   = math.abs   or function(x)    return x < 0 and -x or x end
   math.floor = math.floor or function(x)    return x - x%1           end
   math.ceil  = math.ceil  or function(x)    return x + (-x)%1        end
   math.min   = math.min   or function(x, y) return x < y and x or y  end 
   math.max   = math.max   or function(x, y) return x > y and x or y  end
   math.sqrt  = math.sqrt  or function(x)    return x^0.5             end
   math.pow   = math.pow   or function(x, y) return x^y               end

   math.frexp = math.frexp or
      function(x)
         local e = 0
         if x == 0 then
            return x, e
         end
         local sign = x < 0 and -1 or 1
         x = x * sign
         while x >= 1 do
            x = x / 2
            e = e + 1
         end
         while x < 0.5 do
            x = x * 2
            e = e - 1
         end
         return x * sign, e
      end

   math.exp = math.exp or 
      function(x)
         local e, t, k, p = 0, 1, 1
         repeat e, t, k, p = e + t, t * x / k, k + 1, e
         until e == p
         return e
      end

   math.log = math.log or
      function(x)
         assert(x > 0)
         local a, b, c, d, e, f = x < 1 and x or 1/x, 0, 0, 1, 1
         repeat
            repeat
               c, d, e, f = c + d, b * d / e, e + 1, c
            until c == f
            b, c, d, e, f = b + 1 - a * c, 0, 1, 1, b
         until b <= f
         return a == x and -f or f
      end

   math.log10 = math.log10 or
      function(x)
         return math.log(x) / 2.3025850929940459
      end

   math.random = math.random or
      function(m, n)
         if m then
            if not n then
               m, n = 1, m
            end
            local k = n - m + 1
            if k < 1 or k > 2^53 then
               error("Invalid arguments for function 'random()'", 2)
            end
            local width, bits_in_factor, modk
            if k == prev_k then
               width, bits_in_factor = prev_width, prev_bits_in_factor
            else
               local pwr_prev_width = 2^prev_width
               if k > pwr_prev_width / 2 and k <= pwr_prev_width then
                  width = prev_width
               else
                  width = 53
                  local width_low = -1
                  repeat
                     local w = (width_low + width) / 2
                     w = w - w%1
                     if k <= 2^w then
                        width = w
                     else
                        width_low = w
                     end
                  until width - width_low == 1
                  prev_width = width
               end
               bits_in_factor = 0
               local bits_in_factor_high = width + 1
               while bits_in_factor_high - bits_in_factor > 1 do
                  local bits_in_new_factor = (bits_in_factor + bits_in_factor_high) / 2
                  bits_in_new_factor = bits_in_new_factor - bits_in_new_factor%1
                  if k % 2^bits_in_new_factor == 0 then
                     bits_in_factor = bits_in_new_factor
                  else
                     bits_in_factor_high = bits_in_new_factor
                  end
               end
               prev_k, prev_bits_in_factor = k, bits_in_factor
            end
            local factor, saved_bits, saved_bits_qty, pwr_saved_bits_qty = 2^bits_in_factor, 0, 0, 2^0
            k = k / factor
            width = width - bits_in_factor
            local pwr_width = 2^width
            local gap = pwr_width - k
            repeat
               modk = get_random_bits(width - saved_bits_qty) * pwr_saved_bits_qty + saved_bits
               local modk_in_range = modk < k
               if not modk_in_range then
                  local interval = gap
                  saved_bits = modk - k
                  saved_bits_qty = width - 1
                  pwr_saved_bits_qty = pwr_width / 2
                  repeat
                     saved_bits_qty = saved_bits_qty - 1
                     pwr_saved_bits_qty = pwr_saved_bits_qty / 2
                     if pwr_saved_bits_qty <= interval then
                        if saved_bits < pwr_saved_bits_qty then
                           interval = nil
                        else
                           interval = interval - pwr_saved_bits_qty
                           saved_bits = saved_bits - pwr_saved_bits_qty
                        end
                     end
                  until not interval
               end
            until modk_in_range
            return m + modk * factor + get_random_bits(bits_in_factor)
         else
            return get_53_random_bits() / 2^53
         end
      end

   local orig_Sleep = Sleep
   function Sleep(x)
      return orig_Sleep(x - x%1)
   end

end
```