# Writing an autoclicker script with Lua

Tags: lua, click, syntax-error, logitech-gaming-software

I was trying to make an autoclicker script in Logitech GHUB, which uses Lua. I have tried many variations, but I always get syntax errors. I have no previous experience with coding.

The point of the code is that when I hold P the mouse repeatedly clicks and waits a random interval between these clicks. Also planning to make intervals between Press and Release.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    --OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")

if IsKeyPressed("P") then 
    repeat 
        PressMouseButton(1)
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(math.random(29, 36)) 
        PressMouseButton(1)
        ReleaseMouseButton(1) ---- Syntax Error(Show up almost everywhere when I change the code) 
    until not IsKeyPressed("P") then 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is impossible.
G-Hub is unable to determine is `P` key pressed or released.
Only mouse buttons are monitored (use `IsMouseButtonPressed`).
And `Shift/Alt/Ctrl` keys are also monitored (use `IsModifierPressed`).
Usual keys (letters, digits) are not monitored.

G-Hub has a bug: in compile-time error messages the line numbers are shifted by one.
So, the syntax error actually points to the line with `until not IsKeyPressed("P")` because of the keyword `then`.
And, by the way, there is no function `IsKeyPressed()` defined in G-Hub.
You can read list of all G-Hub functions in menu `Help -> Scripting API`

The following code is an example of autoclicker controlled by Mouse Button #4 ("back") instead of key `P`:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   --OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then 
      repeat 
         PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
         Sleep(math.random(30, 60)) 
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
   end
end
```

Comment: I copied your code into GHUB, and I get this message back: [string LuaVM"]:1: attempt to call a nil value (global 'EnablePrimaryMouseEvents'). Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Yes, wrong function name.  Answer updated.

Comment: Still get an error: [string LuaVM"]:8: attempt to index a nil value (global 'math'). I assume this has something to do with "math.random". With the current script pressing/holding mouse button #4 only gives one click. Would it also be possible to add an interval between the press and release of mouse button #1?

Comment: About `math`: it's a bug in the latest release of G-Hub.  The bug will probably be fixed in the next G-Hub release.  As for now, insert [this big code block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65344300/1847592) at the very beginning of your script.