# ERROR: [string "LuaVM"]:219: attempt to index a nil value (global 'math')

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I get an error in the script below. I wrote the error code and lines under the script. Please help someone. I have been getting this error for a few days.

These are the lines with errors

[string "LuaVM"]:219: attempt to index a nil value (global 'math')

```
function convert_sens(unconvertedSens) 
return 0.002 * math.pow(10, unconvertedSens / 50)
end

function calc_sens_scale(sensitivity)
return convert_sens(sensitivity)/convert_sens(50)
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [math library is missing in the latest update of Logitech G-Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316973/math-library-is-missing-in-the-latest-update-of-logitech-g-hub)

Comment: Copy [this block of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65344300/1847592) at the very beginning of your script. It will restore most useful `math` functions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Lua interpreter you are using doesn't pre-load `math` library. You can try adding `local math = require "math"` statement at the beginning of your script, but if this doesn't work, you need to provide more details about your Lua environment. It's possible that access to the `math` library is not provided.

Comment: `require` is absent (due to sandboxing) in the Lua environment used by OP.

Comment: Then check ```math``` with ```assert``` first: ```assert(math,'math is absent')``` - Is ```math``` in ```package.loaded``` ?

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi - whole `package` table is absent (due to sandboxing) in the Lua environment used by OP.