# math.pow with Logitech G-Hub

Tags: lua, logitech

Not to sure how to fix this error. I read there was a change but have no idea how to fix it.

```
function convert_sens(unconvertedSens) 
    return 0.002 * math.pow(10, unconvertedSens / 50) end
```

The error code was:

> attempt to call a nil value (field 'pow')

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316973/math-library-is-missing-in-the-latest-update-of-logitech-g-hub - @Egor Skriptunoff' answer and his workaround to get the ```math``` functions back

Answer (score 1):

`math.pow` is deprecated since Lua 5.3  and even if your framework doesn't provide any math library simply use the exponentiation operator `^`.

So instead of `math.pow(x, y)` simply write `x^y`

Comment: Deprecated, but still available even in 5.4, so this is still a bit weird.